# Why do I not get confidence intervals for interactions using confint with glmmTMB (nbinom2) and REML=TRUE

Tags: confidence-interval, lsmeans, glmmtmb, reml

I run a model where I test the effects of different parameters on the number of individuals (no_ind) in a field experiment.
I would like to report the confidence intervals and use confint() which works fine for the first model (bee1). However, I get a different, shorter output when using REML=TRUE.

I run following model:

```
bee1=glmmTMB(no_ind~osr_fa+ erd.sc + group+  (osr_fa:group) +
               (1|region_ID/location/run),  
             data=d, family="nbinom2")
#and use 
round(confint(bee1),3)

#This is the output I get: 
> round(confint(bee1),3)
                                                   2.5 % 97.5 % Estimate
cond.(Intercept)                                   0.364  1.396    0.880
cond.osr_fa                                       -0.369  0.127   -0.121
cond.erd.sc                                        0.023  0.407    0.215
cond.groupbb                                      -0.720  0.091   -0.315
cond.groupwb                                      -0.848 -0.042   -0.445
cond.osr_fa:groupbb                               -0.860 -0.031   -0.446
cond.osr_fa:groupwb                               -0.026  0.708    0.341
run:(location:region_ID).cond.Std.Dev.(Intercept)  0.000    Inf    0.000
location:region_ID.cond.Std.Dev.(Intercept)        0.000    Inf    0.000
region_ID.cond.Std.Dev.(Intercept)                 0.357  1.110    0.630
sigma                                              0.940  2.051    1.388


#When I run the same model with REML=TRUE I get the following output: 

bee1.reml=glmmTMB(no_ind~osr_fa+ erd.sc + group+  (osr_fa:group) +
                    (1|region_ID/location/run), 
                   data=d,  family="nbinom2", REML=TRUE)

> round(confint(bee1.reml),3)
                  2.5 % 97.5 % Estimate
cond.(Intercept)  0.314  1.421    0.867
cond.osr_fa      -0.373  0.134   -0.120
cond.erd.sc       0.019  0.410    0.215
cond.groupbb     -0.717  0.109   -0.304
```

Could someone explain why I do not get the confidence intervals and estimates for all other parameters using confint(bee1.reml)?

I have been reading through many pages but could not find an answer to my problem and would be really thankful for some help.

Thanks
Svenja